# Empty Junk in OWA sends non-read responses

Tags: email-client, exchange-2010, outlook-web-access

I have set "Settings -> Mail -> Read Receipts: never" in my Outlook Web App (Exchange 2010SP3UR8+) settings. However I noticed that after emptying my Junk folder there was a bounce for a "Subject: Not read: xxx" mail.

So it looks like OWA has - without asking - sent non-read receipts for mails in the cleaned junk folder. Something I clearly not want. Is there a way to turn this off (for my client or on the exchange server).

In the past I had a mail gateway to the internet which removed all those disposition request headers, but that is no longer in place.

Comment: This is expected behavior when deleting unread messages that requested a read receipt. This cannot be stopped on the client side, but it is possible to [prevent Read Receipts from being sent](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2011/02/23/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-read-receipts-and-delivery-reports-but-were-understandably-afraid-to-ask/) at the Exchange Server.

Comment: I don’t think it is expected to sent ‚non read‘ receipts if I configure it to not send ‚read receipts‘. Especially not from the junk folder.

Comment: I've seen this happen plenty of times, including on systems that have "don't send read receipt" enabled.